Astronomical Horizon VS Apparent/Visible Horizon VS Geometric Horizon
The definition I got for the astronomical horizon is this:
The astronomical horizon is the imaginary horizontal plane always at a 90-degree angle from the observer's zenith (the point directly above the observer).
The definition of apparent horizon came as:
The apparent horizon is the irregular boundary between the Earth's surface and the sky, as seen from a specific vantage point. It's also known as the visible horizon.
The geometric horizon is:
The geometric horizon, the local horizon, is the visible boundary between the Earth and the sky. It's the point where the line of sight from the observer's eye is tangent to the ground.
Can someone please explain their differences to me and point out any mistakes?

Welcome to Physics SE. You have three definitions right there; what differences are you looking for that you cannot tell for yourself?

@controlgroup Feels like they are the same thing, astronomical and apparent horizon. A diagram would help. Thanks

The astronomical is the theoretical ideal plane that is perpendicular to your zenith; the apparent is the actual horizon as seen by you (which is what you state in the post).

@controlgroup Oh! Got it. How idiotic can I be?!
